# How to get directory name from path in Java?

Tags: java, list, directory, path

I'm listing all the folders that are in a Server. 
All the folders are located like this :

=> Ex1 : "C:\A\AB\ABC\FolderToListA-someText"

=> Ex2 : "C:\D\DE\DEF\FolderToListB-someText"

I would like to get the FolderToLists but only returning it once. And not the number of times that are subdirectories.

I've listed every folder and tried using String [] parts, but the problem is that when I list every folder in the parent directory I get duplicate "FolderToList"

Ex: FolderToList contains 2 directories it will return twice de FolderToList.

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < folderOrigin.length; j++) 
{
    if(folderOrigin[j].toString().contains("-") && folderOrigin[j].length() > 29)
    {   
        String fds = folderOrigin[j].toString();;
        fds = fds.substring(0,29);

        String [] parts = fds.split("\\\\"); 
        String designation = parts[parts.length-1];     
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be "FolderToListA","FolderToListB", and not "FolderToListA" "FolderToListA" depending on the subdirectories in FolderA same thing for FolderB

Comment: where do you get that `folderOrigin` array?

Comment: What is the situation this code comes into play? Have you considered using `java.nio.Path` for accessing the file system?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you just don't want doubles?
If so, you just need to add every designation in your for loop in a Set, to avoid doubles.

Like this:

```
Set<String> designations = new HashSet<String>(); 

for(int j = 0 ; j < folderOrigin.length; j++) {

  if(folderOrigin[j].toString().contains("-") && folderOrigin[j].length() > 29){

    String fds = folderOrigin[j].toString();;
    fds = fds.substring(0,29);

    String [] parts = fds.split("\\\\"); 
    String designation = parts[parts.length-1];
    designations.add(parts[parts.length-1]);
   }
}
```